# Powershell Output Braces

Tags: powershell

If I am enter following command:

```
$ Get-SCClass -Name Microsoft.Windows.Client.Win10.Aggregate.LogicalDisk | Get-SCOMClassInstance | Select-Object Values
```

The Output looks like this:
[image: Powershell Output]

How can I grab the first entry (137739444224) of this output?
I want to use this number.

Comment of @Olaf was close:
[image: Olaf Output]

best regards

Comment: Can you try piping the result to `gm` and see what type it is?

Comment: How about `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Values | Select-Object -First 1`?

Comment: @Olaf that was close. I add a picture above of your output.

Comment: OK, then ... `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Values | Select-Object -First 1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value`?

Comment: @Olaf there we go. the error is still appearing but the value is comming out. thx man. Can you post an answer that I can accept this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one of the properties you get back from the pipeline is an array you can expand it with `Select-Object -ExpandProperty <PropertyName>` ...

```
Get-SCClass -Name Microsoft.Windows.Client.Win10.Aggregate.LogicalDisk | 
    Get-SCOMClassInstance | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Values | 
            Select-Object -First 1 | 
                Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
```

Another option would be to use the "*dot notation*"

```
(Get-SCClass -Name Microsoft.Windows.Client.Win10.Aggregate.LogicalDisk | Get-SCOMClassInstance ).Values[0].Value
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to expand a property, then get the first element of the array.  You can use foreach-object or % to do that as well.

```
[pscustomobject]@{Values=1377739444224, 'C:', 'NTFS', $false} | % values

1377739444224
C:
NTFS
False


[pscustomobject]@{Values=1377739444224, 'C:', 'NTFS', $false} | % values | 
  select -first 1

1377739444224
```

Or

```
[pscustomobject]@{Values=1377739444224, 'C:', 'NTFS', $false} | % {$_.values[0]}

1377739444224
```